# Get full page URL using php with port number and https

Tags: php

I was looking for the php function that will return the full page url of the page (even rewritten with htaccess).

function returning for example:

```
https://google.com:8000/yourfolder/yourpage.html
```

Comment: i'm using Vue CLI port forwarding locally so what i needed was `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT']`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function fullpageurl() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}
?>
```

**Explanation**

using `$_SERVER["HTTPS"]` to check if the SSL is `ON` or `OFF`
using `$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]` to check the port number of the website accessed
using `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` to get the website host.
using `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` to get the current page.